# URl Issue In Interspire Shopping Cart

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, interspire-shopping-cart

1. My urls seems to be changed since i transfer my site from GoDaddy to myhosting.
   On godaddy my site was very slow. So i decided to move it to Myhosting. But i see that URLs of my site have been changed.
   See this link.

   http://www.bontonwear.com/products.php?product=Guardians-of-the-Galaxy-Jacket
   http://www.bontonwear.com/products/Guardians-of-the-Galaxy-Jacket.html
   http://www.bontonwear.com/products/Guardians-of-the-Galaxy-Jacket

As u can see that these all URL's are changed but it all open up the same product.
I want it to be look like this.

```
http://www.bontonwear.com/products/Guardians-of-the-Galaxy-Jacket.html
```

same goes with the simple page.

```
http://www.bontonwear.com/pages/contact-us.html
http://www.bontonwear.com/pages/contact-us
http://www.bontonwear.com/pages.php?pageid=10
```

so  how i'm gonna achieve it , through .htaccess or is there any way plz help me out.
My .htaccess file

```
https://www.dropbox.com/s/6x7ebzhb4b2lpm8/.htaccess
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In:

Admin->Settings->Store Settings

look for 
Search Engine Friendly URLs:

and set to enable if available or yes but note if you set it to yes and your htaccess is not working right then your pages will not load.

Your htaccess file looks customized.

If you need the default htaccess file for comparison here is mine (this is for ISC 6.1.1):

```
Options -MultiViews +FollowSymlinks -Indexes

# Force 401 pages to use a valid error document
# so they do not fall back to the 404 which is
# triggered by ISC. This allows HTTP Auth to work
# correctly
ErrorDocument 401 "Unauthorized access"

<IfModule mod_security.c>
    # Turn off mod_security filtering.
    SecFilterEngine Off

    # The below probably isn't needed, but better safe than sorry.
    SecFilterScanPOST Off
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    # If your server is running PHP in CGI mode you will probably need to uncomment the following lines
    # Only uncomment lines that begine with Rewrite

    # The RewriteBase should be set to the same value as the AppPath setting in your config.php WITH a / on the end
    # RewriteBase /

    # This rewrite base rule is only required if you are getting 401 unauthorized errors when placing an order with Google Checkout
    # RewriteRule .* - [E=REMOTE_USER:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
    #
    # Alternatively, if the above does not work, try uncommenting this line below instead:
    # SetEnvIfNoCase Authorization "Basic ([a-z0-9=]+)" REMOTE_AUTHORIZATION=$1

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} robots.txt
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule robots.txt robots_default.txt [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . index.php
    <IfModule mod_env.c>
        SetEnv SEO_SUPPORT 1
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript text/css text/html text/xml
</IfModule>
```

Comment: thanks henry you answer resoled my issue.I look up for look for Search Engine Friendly URLs in admin/store settings .In 
Search Engine Friendly URLs i select yes, enable search engine friendly URLs.
and that did resolve my issue. :)